# SQLite query to join on a range of dates?

Tags: sql, datetime, sqlite

I am working with SQLite.

Suppose I have a table `sales` with two columns, `date` and `count`, to keep track of how many glasses of lemonade I sold on that date. If I don't sell any lemonade on a given day, I am too depressed to create a new row in the `sales` table.

I'd like to find out the average number of glasses sold over a given date range. I could issue a query like this:

```
SELECT AVG(count) FROM sales WHERE date IS BETWEEN '2010-01-04' AND '2010-01-10';
```

However, the result won't be accurate unless all of the dates in that range are included in the table. I need some way to tell SQLite to count the missing rows as zeroes.

I imagine if I could join the sales table on a date range, that would be ideal. That doesn't seem to be possible, so a simple way of creating a table from a date range is probably the next best thing. I don't want to modify the sales table, which seems silly for a lemonade stand but makes more sense in the real life counterpart.

As I said above, I am using SQLite, so you are not being helpful if you recommend other databases to me. That said, if you have more experience with another database and think your solution can be done in vanilla SQL, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: can you say anything about the range? should it be arbitrary length? or is there a maximum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a calendar table and join onto that:

Something like this will do:

```
create table dates (id integer primary key);
insert into dates default values;
insert into dates default values;
insert into dates select null from dates d1, dates d2, dates d3 , dates d4;
insert into dates select null from dates d1, dates d2, dates d3 , dates d4;
alter table dates add date datetime;
update dates set date=date('2000-01-01',(-1+id)||' day');
```

That will cover you till 2287-05-20
Adding an index to the date column in the dates table won't hurt. My sqlite is little rusty, so I suggest you consult [the manual](http://sqlite.org/lang.html) on that.

**Edit:** Code for the index:

```
create unique index ux_dates_date on dates (date);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT sum(count) / ((strftime('%s','2010-01-10')-strftime('%s','2010-01-04')+86400)/86400)
FROM sales
WHERE date IS BETWEEN '2010-01-04' AND '2010-01-10';
```

The query calculates the exact number of days by taking the seconds between the given dates
and dividing with 86400 (= 24*3600) secs.

For example

```
SELECT (strftime('%s','2010-03-01')-strftime('%s','2010-01-01') + 86400) / 86400
```

outputs `60` which is the correct value.

Check out SQLite's [Date And Time Functions.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: clever! I was thinking of something way too complicated.

Comment: This is good but it only works for computing an average. I have some more complicated stuff I want to do where that isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Recursive Common Table expression to generate a series of dates and join to it:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(x) AS (
    SELECT 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT x+1 FROM cnt
    LIMIT (SELECT ((julianday('2010-01-10') - julianday('2010-01-04'))) + 1)
), 
WITH date_series AS (
  SELECT date(julianday('2010-01-04'), '+' || x || ' days') as date 
FROM date_series ds
)
SELECT AVG(COALESCE(s.count, 0)) as avg_sales_count
FROM date_series ds
  LEFT JOIN sales s ON ds.date = s.date
```

I wrote a blog post with more info here: http://www.geekytidbits.com/generate-date-range-sqlite/