# Return a zero for a day with no results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which returns the total of users who registered for each day. Problem is if a day had no one register it doesn't return any value, it just skips it. I would rather it returned zero

this is my query so far

```
SELECT count(*) total FROM users WHERE created_at < NOW() AND created_at > 
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND owner_id = ? GROUP BY DAY(created_at) 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

**Edit**

i grouped the data so i would get a count for each day- As for the date range, i wanted the total users registered for the previous seven days

Comment: For which set of days? All of time? That would be a big result set. You're grouping by days - grouping doesn't usually return entries where there are no groups for a particular group key...

Comment: Just wanted to say, can't your app logic do this? The less data a SQL query returns the better.  Less data = faster. I'm sure your app logic could do this easily.

I'm sure SQL could be done, it will be less efficient and do you reall need it?

Comment: One way to accomplish what you want is to think of your query as a JOIN against a range of dates. Here's a question about that, with some answers: > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045015/sqlite-query-to-join-on-a-range-of-dates

Comment: use a [calendar table](http://crazycoders.net/2012/03/using-a-calendar-table-in-mysql/)

Comment: i grouped the data so i would get a count for each day- i wanted the total users registered for the previous seven days

Answer (score 1):

A variation on the theme "build your on 7 day calendar inline":

```
SELECT D, count(created_at) AS total FROM
(SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL D DAY) AS D
    FROM
    (SELECT 0 as D
     UNION SELECT 1
     UNION SELECT 2
     UNION SELECT 3
     UNION SELECT 4
     UNION SELECT 5
     UNION SELECT 6
     ) AS D
) AS D
LEFT JOIN users ON date(created_at) = date(D)
WHERE owner_id = ? or  owner_id is null
GROUP BY D 
ORDER BY D DESC
```

I don't have your table structure at hand, so that would need adjustment probably. In the same order of idea, you will see I use `NOW()` as a reference date. But that's easily adjustable. Anyway that's the spirit...

See for a live demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab5cf/11

Answer (score 0):

If you had a table that held all of your days you could do a left join from there to your users table.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN U.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM DimDate D
LEFT JOIN Users U ON CONVERT(DATE,U.Created_at) = D.DateValue
WHERE YourCriteria
GROUP BY YourGroupBy
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit long winded, but I think this will work...

```
SELECT count(users.created_at) total FROM
  (SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 DAY) as cdate UNION ALL
   SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 5 DAY) UNION ALL
   SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 4 DAY) UNION ALL
   SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 3 DAY) UNION ALL
   SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY) UNION ALL
   SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) UNION ALL
   SELECT CURDATE()) t1 left join users
ON date(created_at)=t1.cdate 
WHERE owner_id = ? or owner_id is null
GROUP BY t1.cdate 
ORDER BY t1.cdate DESC
```

It differs from your query slightly in that it works on dates rather than date times which your query is doing.  From your description I have assumed you mean to use whole days and therefore have used dates.

Comment: What is the definition of your users table?

Answer (score 0):

The tricky bit is that you group by the date field in your data, which might have 'holes' in it, and thus miss records for that date.

A way to solve it is by filling a table with all dates for the past 10 and next 100 years or so, and to (outer)join that to your data. Then you will have one record for each day (or week or whatever) for sure.

I had to do this only for MS SqlServer, so how to fill a date table (or perhaps you can do it dynamically) is for someone else to answer.